# Which caste is "software developer"?

Tags: dharma, caste-system, dharma-shastras, varna, varnashrama

Advocates of the varnashrama dharma claim that we should follow the varna professions listed in the dharma shastras. [For example:](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201779.html)

> 10.47 - For Sūtas, the management of horses and chariots; for Ambaṣṭhas, the art of healing; for Vaidehakas, the service of women;
> and for Māgadhas, trade.
>
> 10.48 - For Niṣādas, the killing of fish; for Āyogavas, carpentry; and for medas, andhras, Cuñcus and Madgus, the killing of wild animals.

But there is no mention of "software developer", "IT specialist", "engineer", etc. The implication then would be that Indians should not do these jobs, and thus India should not have a modern infrastructure or use modern technology.

But rationally we can understand that these jobs are not mentioned because the dharma shastras were written in the bronze age (3000 BC+) by pundits who were not aware of changes in society that would take place in the future such as modern technology and modern jobs. They assumed that people would still ride horses, chariots, fight with bows, arrows, and swords, etc.

So, we can see that material duties change with time, but spiritual duties, like service to one's parents, do not change.

Comment: Engineers are Shudras for they produce labour.

Comment: @Wikash_ Actually shudras are supposed to be servants to dvijas, like being a personal butler. Actual carpenters, laborers, etc. are mixed caste pratilomas.

Comment: They are a mix of brahmin and shudra, because they do brain-labor for others. In past, brahmins used to do yagnas (development) for others, teach (workshop) others and used to get donation. Now they do same, but get salary. 
*"pundits who were not aware of changes in society. The implication then would be that Indians should not do these jobs"* - lol, how is that the *implication*? Any rule, written at any time, for any time, naturally cannot list every item/job/person in the world. Does it mean those things are not covered by the rule ?

Comment: A computer is just electricity (vidyut) through semiconductors (sand). If any brahmin, vaishya or kshatriya used these combinations in the past, and any shudra helped them in this endeavor, then "software engineer" is covered by shastras. Did you possibly wonder that Shastras know, but still, do not care about these mundane modern technological terms ? You think Bhagavan/rishis who wrote rules for Krita Yug are incapable of writing rules for Kali. Well, they did. That rule is nama sankirtan and/or surrender. The rest, they left upto people cos they know people wouldn't listen to rules anyway

Comment: "But there is no mention of "software developer", "IT specialist", "engineer", etc." I haven't looked into it but I think the purana about the Kalki avatar describes highly advanced technology (like floating castles and high speed vehicles). Maybe an engineer is described in it.

Comment: @mar Computer is a modern technology, so it's not covered by shastras. We can't make connections between "sand and lightning" to "computers and software developers" because that's clearly not the intention.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - how do you know that's not the intention ? Even when shastras wrote about bows and arrows for their supposed time of "bronze age" (whatever nonsensical historical term this is), they didn't mention Nagastra by name. yet arjuna used it. Does it mean shastras were unaware of them ? No. because shastras are bird's eye view of world. they don't need to mention each and everything to cover it. Shastras do not mention Bill Gates by name, does it mean they don't have rules for Vaishyas ?

Comment: @mar "how do you know that's not the intention ?" - Because when "sand" and "vidyut" are used in the shastras, they are not describing computers. Plus electricity was not harnessed until modern times. Shastras assume people will still be using horses, chariots, and bows/arrows, not cars, airplanes, or machine guns. Drinking from river rather than having modern plumbing system, etc. There are so many examples.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - *"Shastras assume people will still be using horses"* - nope, you assume that shastras assume that. my stance is that shastras only made rules for people that will follow rules. they know that kali yug librandus will not follow, so what's the point of writing a rule for using an iPhone or Tesla. shastras know people won't even know sanskrit. like i said earlier, not all combinations of items need to be described for a rule to be effective. if a rule says 2-wheelers must stop at red light, that includes both a red and a blue two wheeler. when shastras say weapons, includes nuclear

Comment: @mar Shastra says kshatriyas should fight with horses, chariots, bows, etc. These words are all very clearly understood in Sanskrit. It doesn't use words like "machine gun", "nuclear bomb", etc. These words don't exist in Sanskrit, because the technology didn't exist. Also, do you know what happened when horses were used against machine guns in world war 1? They lost the battle.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - shastras don't say they must fight ONLY using those. and people did use astra/shastras at that time - shooting multiple arrows at once - these were the machine guns of old, one arrow causing a fireball - these were the napalms of old. so it's factually incorrect to say that shastras do not know about advanced weapons. and even people fighting with horses against horses lost, irrelevant point.

Comment: @Ikshvaku *" It doesn't use words like "machine gun", "nuclear bomb", etc. These words don't exist in Sanskrit, because the technology didn't exist. "* <--- It doesn't have to be, right? If you look at Narayanastra, it is capable of destroying whole planet. Isn't it? What I feel is Shastras when they say "astra", that would mean any weapon not just sword, gada or bow-arrow.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Sure, but what about airplanes, submarines, battleships, etc. Sure there were vimanas, but only a few people had it, not entire armies with aerial battles. And there especially weren't any submarines or battle ships.

Comment: @mar Those machine gun bows, brahmastras, etc. were used by highly specialized soldiers, not the average foot soldier. Also shastra doesn't mention submarines, battleships (naval battles on sea, since you can't even enter the ocean), or airplanes. Sure few powerful people had vimanas, but armies didn't have hundreds of vimanas and aerial battles. Devas and asuras did but not human armies.

Comment: @mar "and even people fighting with horses against horses lost, irrelevant point." - Manusmriti says a kshatriya should fight using horses a flat open field. If you followed that today, you will lose against machine guns.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - regarding submarines, mahabharata mentions bhima meeting nagas under water when he was poisoned and thrown in river. it mentions duryodhan holding his breath inside a lake for an hour or more. if people had that much physical strength, maybe they didn't need submarines. again i think you're arguing for the sake of it. even if mahabharat mentioned weapons of mass destruction like brahmastra, you're going to say mahabharat did not mention the word "ICBM" so they are irrelevant/outdated.

Comment: @mar I'm arguing to show that we can't follow some rules in scripture because they are outdated. These are different weapons systems; brahmastras are magical weapons created with mantras, whereas ICBMs follow the laws of physics. Is Putin going to chant a mantra when he launches nukes? Also there no satellites, unmanned-drones, electronic warfare, EMP bombs, lasers, etc. So many examples of modern weapons. What are you basically arguing is that technology is adharmic because there is no caste that can create technology.

Comment: See. The traditional Shudra professions include things like pottery, shilpa (sculpting), shoe work, the sort of laborious service work that aids the dvijas. Here too, the people are putting in labour to produce a product that would aid the dvijas. Hence software developer is a Shudra. If he codes an ERP, it would serve Vaishyas for their business. If they made a Jyotisha software, it would serve Brahmins. If they produced something general like YouTube, it is for the benefit of all classes similar to actors entertaining and serving the entire society and being classified as shudras.

Comment: now your question should be, among the existing categories of Shudras like potters, actors, sculptors etc, can we create new categories of Shudras called software developer, and if yes, then from which traditional lineage must such people be procured? Is it correct to make potters software developers and tell them to leave their hereditary business and so also for the other cases. Should the be taken from kayasthas who used to do traditional coding and documentation work?

Comment: @Adiyarkku Fair points. "Is it correct to make potters software developers and tell them to leave their hereditary business and so also for the other cases. Should the be taken from kayasthas who used to do traditional coding and documentation work?" - Yes, that's a possibility. Also I think Indian society did 100-200 years ago when India was becoming modernized and technologized.

Comment: What did India do when it was becoming modernised?

Comment: @Adiyarkku This part: "then from which traditional lineage must such people be procured? Is it correct to make potters software developers and tell them to leave their hereditary business and so also for the other cases. Should the be taken from kayasthas who used to do traditional coding and documentation work?" - I think that's what they did. Brahmins were given scholarly jobs. Rajputs, sikhs, etc. transitioned into the modern military and trained with modern arms.

Comment: @mar No one today can launch brahmastras and other magical weapons. No one even knows the mantras anymore or has mantra siddhi. So this is all the more reason to adopt modern technology and not bronze age warfare of the shastras: swords, bows, chariots, etc. And by the way, the chariot fell out of use by the end of the bronze age. Around 500 BC (iron age time), armies stopped using chariots. So from this we can see how *ancient* the scriptures are.

Comment: You are trying to make these shastra verses valid in modern times by trying to connect magical bows with machine guns, etc. It doesn't work, a bow is a bow, not a machine gun. A chariot is a simple vehicle pulled by a horse, not a modern armored vehicle. These connections are what people would call "grasping at straws". If we are being honest, we'll admit that these were written in ancient times for ancient people, not modern people with technology.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - *"No one today can launch brahmastras and other magical weapons."* - they can launch weapons with similar destructive power. the inability to make these connections is what i would call wilful ignorance. If we are being honest, we'll admit that these were written in ancient times for all people.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - "adopt modern technology and not bronze age warfare of the shastras: swords, bows, chariots, etc." - did i say we shouldn't adopt modern technology ? i'm saying the lack of mention of modern english words in a sanskrit text does not mean the sanskrit text is ignorant of modern society - whereas you are saying it does. it just means you don't think highly of the tri-kala-jnana-tvam of shastra-kartas, whereas I do.

Comment: @mar Similar destructive power is purely a coincidence, and that's only comparing nuclear bombs and brahmastras. But look at everything else: electronic warfare like hacking, EMPs, internet, computers, light bulbs, etc. There are so many things in modern technology that have no parallel in ancient texts.

Comment: @mar "did i say we shouldn't adopt modern technology ?" - Well, we would have to go back to the other topic of 'which caste will work that technology?' :D

Comment: @mar "it just means you don't think highly of the tri-kala-jnana-tvam of shastra-kartas, whereas I do." - They didn't see EVERYTHING in the future. What they knew is that dharma declines as the yugas progress.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - you think this is their first time meeting kali yug ? Manu, author of Manu Smriti, rules for 1 manvantara, which equals 14 chaturyugas. this current kali, being the 28th, would be his 14th time looking at kali yug. it's not FUTURE for them. It's the PAST. and they're quite well qualified to comment on the past because future replicates it. They say which Smriti is to be followed in which Yug. And if a Smriti doesn't mention rules for "computer engineers", it means it doesn't care what rules those people follow, just like it doesn't care what rules dogs/cats follow.

Comment: I mean it depends I would argue Shudra though. They work for a master (corporation) all be it with pay. Although one could argue the same for any Varna. Hard to determine.

Answer (score 0):

From Varnashrama dharma;

Manu -
"The fourth Varna can easily perform their Dharmas. They can worship God in their homes (Applicable to every body), should do service to Brahmins and produce things which are required by others."

Artisans and the like, who produce articles for others, among which the software developer's trade is categorized, is a sudra's occupation.

Comment: Welcome to the Hinduism Stack Exchange! You need to cite some sources while answering questions. Visit FAQ section at [help] to learn more about sources and citations.

Answer (score -1):

As the name suggests "Developer", Software Developer comes under the category vaishya varna. Because mainly vaishya varna creates, develop, grow and produce.

Comment: For vaishyas, only profession is vegetable farming (social websites wrongly mention trade as duty of vaishya ; trade = shudra + mixedcaste

Comment: No, Vaishyas are not only vegetable farmers, there are many other occupations that comes under vaishyas, In present times those who Vishwakarma(carpenter, designer), Prajapati(clay worker) and others also comes under this category

Comment: I am not referring to present day situation of vaishyas. I m referring to vaishya duty as per scriptures.